# to detect at least three letter or number regexp

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need a RegExp code as follows: 3 letters or numbers side by side again, not more than

examples:

- `aab` is **valid**
- `aaa` is **not valid**
- `abc`  is **valid**
- `aabbcc` is **valid**
- `aabbbcc` is **not valid** (bbb)
- `aa22cc`  is **valid**
- `aa222cc` is **not valid** (222)
- `xxxxxxxxxxx` is **not valid**
- `111111111` is **not valid**
- `xx11xx11` is **valid**

I do this to verify the actual

Comment: Atleast make an attempt to finish the question.

Comment: Shouldn't `aabbbaa` be not valid?

Comment: @DMK: Yes, the original question in fact read like that.

Comment: @Jon - that'd be my bad.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make sure there are no more than two consecutive identical characters, you can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/(.)\1{2}/
```

This expression will match any character that is followed by two more copies of itself. So, to make sure that there is no three-character-repetition, check the the regex does not match:

```
if(!preg_match('/(.)\1{2}/', $input)) {
    // "valid"
}
```

Comment: However, it doesn't check whether the string only contains digits and letters.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: There is no sample input that reveals such a requirement, so I didn't include it. Another way to read the question is that runs of three identical characters are allowed *unless* the character is a letter or number. It really is badly worded, so I went just by the examples.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: 
I think working correctly.
look at pls.
http://rubular.com/r/WieqpnUIDh

Comment: @merakli: Well, your question suggests that you would not want to match `john..delo` because it contains characters other than letters/digits. I'm pretty sure that's why you received so many downvotes (not by me, by the way): Your question is vague and incomplete, you haven't specified your requirements clearly, and there is no visible effort on your part to solve the problem.

Comment: how to write this validation with javascript?
} Else if (username.match (/ (.) \ 1 {2} /)) {
This code does not work

Comment: @merakli: Now that you know what the correct regular expression is, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). All the information you need is there. Specifically look at the `test` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have two requirements (it seems):

1. Ensure that the string contains only ASCII digits and letters.
2. Ensure that there are no more than two consecutive, identical letters.

This is how you do it:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/^         # Start of string
    (?!         # Assert that it is not possible to match...
     .*         # any string,
     (.)        # followed by any character
     \1{2}      # which is repeated twice.
    )           # (End of lookahead)
    [a-z0-9]*   # Match a string that only contains ASCII letters and digits
    $           # until the end of the string.
    \Z/ix',     # case-insensitive, verbose regex
    $subject)) {
    # Successful match
    }
```

See it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eH4aR3).